# How to set array of colors using vba?

Tags: vba, vb6

I wish to set Array of colors using VBA.

that was not simple as i thought it would be.

using `Vb.NET` you can declare array of color like that:

```
Dim ar() As Color = {Color.Yellow, Color.Red, Color.Green}
```

so i tried something similer in VBA (and was not so surprised that compilation error was thrown, i wonder what data type is `vbYellow`(`Enum`?)):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ar(3) As Object
Dim a, b, c As Object

Set a = vbYellow
Set b = vbRed
Set c = vbGreen

ar(0) = a
ar(1) = b
ar(2) = c

End Sub
```

thank you.

Comment: Generally you can right click on any identifier in the VB6 IDE, select "Go to Definition" and it will show you its data type, etc. That would make it clear that vbYellow was just a numeric code (long) and not an object type.

Comment: thank you, i tried to find something like that in the IDE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vbYellow` returns a numeric value, so you need to define your variable as `Long`. So, there is no need to `Set` it before.

You could use direct approach, with `ar(0) = vbYellow` (you don't need the `a,`b`and`c` variables as the "middle-man").

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ar(3) As Long
Dim a As Long, b As Long, c As Long

a = vbYellow
b = vbRed
c = vbGreen

ar(0) = a
ar(1) = b
ar(2) = c

End Sub
```

Comment: thx, so a color is not an object in vba...the `Interior.Color` for example takes a long int value...

Comment: @jonathana yes , it also takes `Long`

Answer (score 7):

In VBA/VB6 the `Object` type is reserved for variables that hold an *object reference*. Unlike in .NET, **not everything is an object** - so you can't assign an enum constant (a named `Long` integer, basically) to an object reference.

Instead you use the `Variant` type, and you can inline the array declaration with the `Array` function:

```
Dim colors As Variant
colors = Array(vbRed, vbGreen, vbBlue, vbYellow)
```

---

Also in VB.NET this:

```
Dim a, b, c As Object
```

Declares 3 `Object` variables.

In VBA/VB6 however, that declares `c` as an `Object`, and leaves `a` and `b` as implicit `Variant` variables: you'll want to avoid multiple declarations on the same line.

Comment: i know comments meant to add extra value for the discussion but i must say that your Rubberduck project is very impressive!

Comment: @jonathana thanks! Feel free to star us on GitHub! =)

Answer (score 1):

For VBA you can use this function (I made it and succesfully use in several projects)

```
  Function GetColorFromColrName(ColrName As String) As Long
  Dim rgbc As Long
  Select Case ColrName
    Case "red"
      rgbc = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    Case "brown"
  rgbc = RGB(165, 42, 42)
Case "coral"
  rgbc = RGB(255, 127, 80)
Case "orange red"
  rgbc = RGB(255, 69, 0)
Case "orange"
  rgbc = RGB(255, 165, 0)
Case "gold"
  rgbc = RGB(255, 215, 0)
Case "yellow"
  rgbc = RGB(255, 255, 0)
Case "yellow green"
  rgbc = RGB(154, 205, 50)
Case "lawn green"
  rgbc = RGB(124, 252, 0)
Case "green"
  rgbc = RGB(0, 128, 0)
Case "lime"
  rgbc = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Case "aqua"
  rgbc = RGB(0, 255, 255)
Case "blue"
  rgbc = RGB(0, 0, 255)
Case "blue violet"
  rgbc = RGB(138, 43, 226)
Case "dodgerblue"
  rgbc = RGB(30, 144, 255)
Case "dark magenta"
  rgbc = RGB(139, 0, 139)
Case "dark violet"
  rgbc = RGB(148, 0, 211)
Case "purple"
  rgbc = RGB(128, 0, 128)
Case "magenta"
  rgbc = RGB(255, 0, 255)
Case "chocolate"
  rgbc = RGB(210, 105, 30)
Case "black"
  rgbc = RGB(0, 0, 0)
Case "dim gray"
  rgbc = RGB(105, 105, 105)
Case "gray"
  rgbc = RGB(188, 188, 188)
Case "silver"
  rgbc = RGB(192, 192, 192)
Case "white"
  rgbc = RGB(255, 255, 255)
Case ""

   End Select
   GetColorFromColrName = rgbc
End Function
```

All the best!